# com.android.providers.settings does not exists

Tags: settings

I am using Lineage OS 14.1-20171111_14ß556-UNOFFICIAL-cedric on my Motorola G5
Android 7.1.2 and i am not able to locate the file/data/data/com.android.providers.settings/databases/settings‌​.db

i tried ES File Explorer(with root) , adb shell (with root) and also SQLite Editor from the Play Store does not seem to find that file.

Comment: What shell commands are you using?

Comment: is `com.android.providers.settings` a folder ? also are you sure there is no typo in `...providers...` ? try without the `s` and see if it helps.

Comment: This may help also: https://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=774507

Comment: Why do you need this file?

Comment: @harpratap My case: there should be wifi networks/passwords in it. (The other ways usually require rooted phone.)

Answer (score 3):

Since Marshmallow, all the settings are scattered everywhere, you won't find settings.db

many settings are available under /data/system/users/0/ saved as XMLs. Try looking there.

Comment: What a downgrade!